# Create one figure with two plots next to each other, with one plot containing two Y with one X

Tags: python, data-visualization

I want to create **one figure** with two plots like this.
[image: One figure with two plots]

My codes are:

```
plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.hist(biib_neg_return_price, bins = 100, density = True, facecolor = "g")
plt.plot(x_fit, biib_normal_fit, color = "k", linestyle = "solid", linewidth = 1)
plt.xlabel("BIIB negative return price")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
title_histo = "Histogram of BIIB Negative Return Price"
plt.title(title_histo)
plt.text(-0.4, 25, "skew = %0.2f\n\u03BC = %0.2f\n\u03C3 = %0.2f" % (biib_skew, biib_mu, biib_std))
 
plt.subplot(1,2,2)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(alpha_seq, VaR_history_biib_seq, color = "black", label = "Historical data")
ax.plot(alpha_seq, VaR_normal_biib_seq, color = "olive", label = "Fitted Normal Distribution")
ax.legend(loc = 0)
plt.xlabel("Level \u03B1")
plt.ylabel("Value at Risk")
title_VaR = "Value at Risk for BIIB"
plt.title(title_VaR)
```

However, the results are **two figures** like this.
[image: Figure 1]
[image: Figure 2]
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with something like

```
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)
fig.suptitle('Horizontally stacked subplots')
ax1.plot(x, y)
ax2.plot(x, -y)
```

Like from [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html#stacking-subplots-in-one-direction).